# Exim - Untainting data and Vacation configuration

Tags: router, exim

Good Day!

I am running Exim 4.97.  Trying to configure a per user vacation/out-of-office autoreply.  I have read a bunch of articles and examples from before and after "tainting" was implemented in Exim. Alas, I am still confused as I build the configuration.

Presently, I am having issues getting my router untainted.  Very simply, I have a router:

vacation-domains is a text file containing domain names, 1 per line.
users is a text file in UNIX password format.

I am trying to build the file so I understand what is happening at each step.  I have not even gotten to the transport yet.  :-O

Thank You in Advance for any assistance!!!

glenn

===

QUESTION:

Why does the "local_parts" line not populate $local_part_data?

Why does this router just dump out?

===

vacationUser:

driver = redirect

domains                     = ${lookup{${lc:${domain}}}lsearch,ret=key{/usr/local/etc/exim/vacation-domains}}

local_parts                 = ${lookup{${lc:${local_part}@${domain}}}lsearch,ret=key{/usr/local/etc/dovecot/users}}

file                        = /var/vmail/$domain_data/$local_part_data@$domain_data/.vacation.msg

debug_print                 = ROUTER - $router_name for $local_part@$domain - Local_part_data is $local_part_data - Domain_data is $domain_data

exim -bt -d user@domain.com yields:

--------> vacationUser router <--------

local_part=user domain=domain.com

checking domains

search_open: lsearch "/usr/local/etc/exim/vacation-domains"

cached open

search_find: file="/usr/local/etc/exim/vacation-domains"

key="domain.com" partial=-1 affix=NULL starflags=0 opts="ret=key"

LRU list:

7/usr/local/etc/exim/vacation-domains

7/usr/local/etc/exim/vusers.domain.com

7/usr/local/etc/dovecot/users

End

internal_search_find: file="/usr/local/etc/exim/vacation-domains"

type=lsearch key="domain.com" opts=NULL

cached data used for lookup of domain.com

in /usr/local/etc/exim/vacation-domains

lookup yielded:

domain.com in "domain.com"?

list element: domain.com

domain.com in "domain.com"? yes (matched "domain.com")

checking local_parts

search_open: lsearch "/usr/local/etc/dovecot/users"

cached open

search_find: file="/usr/local/etc/dovecot/users"

key="user@domain.com" partial=-1 affix=NULL starflags=0 opts="ret=key"

LRU list:

7/usr/local/etc/dovecot/users

7/usr/local/etc/exim/vacation-domains

7/usr/local/etc/exim/vusers.domain.com

End

internal_search_find: file="/usr/local/etc/dovecot/users"

type=lsearch key="user@domain.com" opts=NULL

cached data used for lookup of user@domain.com

in /usr/local/etc/dovecot/users

lookup yielded: ENCRYPTED-PASSWORD::::::

user in "user@domain.com"?

list element: user@domain.com

user in "user@domain.com"? no (end of list)

vacationUser router skipped: local_parts mismatch